# Cannot Access Mean Values

Tags: c++, opencv

I have computed mean and standart deviation values of a region in the image. 
The code:

```
Mat img=imread("a.jpg");
Mat hsv1;
Mat mean, stdev;
cvtColor(img, hsv1, CV_BGR2HSV);
cv::meanStdDev(hsv1, mean, stdev, superpixel_mask);
cout << "mean: " << mean << endl << "standard deviation: " << stdev << endl;
```

The output is:

```
mean: [150.8399251737039;
  103.6980224478888;
  226.161411010155]
standard deviation: [23.98981564590477;
  46.73491195049309;
  34.41166394765997]
```

I would like to access those numbers.
I wrote that code:

```
float Mi = mean.at<float>(0,0);
cout << Mi << endl;
```

It gives that error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)si
ze.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channel
s()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3
) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file C:\OpenCV249\opencv\build\
include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp, line 537
```

Comment: google is your friend : http://answers.opencv.org/question/6501/problem-with-meanstddev/

Comment: Why do you think they are called mean values.... big meanies.

Comment: 'C:\OpenCV249\opencv\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp, line 537' IMHO you must to use last version. i am OK with your code using OpenCV 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to access a `CV_64F` `Mat` using `at<float>`.

You can solve this like:

```
double Mi = mean.at<double>(0,0);
```

Or declaring `Scalar` instead of `Mat`:

```
Scalar mean, stdev;
cv::meanStdDev(hsv1, mean, stdev, superpixel_mask);
double Mi = mean[0];
```