# How to extract value from a *CvScalar Output Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, syntax, face-detection

Consider me a newbie at programming. I tried to search for an answer to this question before posting but no luck.

I am using CvAvgSdv function to calculate the Std Deviation and the Mean of the ROI of an image. For reference that is:

```
 cvAvgSdv(LeftROI, LeftMean, LeftStdDev);
```

LeftMean & LeftStdDev are the output arrays in the form of *CvScalar but how do I display them/access the output value? I personally only need the Standard Deviation value as I am calculating the pixel variance in an image. So squaring the Standard Deviation should give me this.

Regards,
Sheraz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Access Mean Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956892/cannot-access-mean-values)

Comment: You should not use obsolete C syntax. Use C++ api instead. You can find an example in the linked question