# how to improve variance calculation performance using integral image in opencv

Tags: opencv, c++11, opencv3.0, micro-optimization

I'm writing c++ image processing project using opencv.
i'm calculating variance of image for each pixel. You may say variance filter. For each pixel i calculate variance around that pixel with filter size. FilterSize much smaller then image size.
For that i used blurring:

```
    blur(workingIm, blurredImage, Size(filterSize, filterSize));
    blur(workingIm.mul(workingIm), blurredSqureImage, Size(filterSize, filterSize));
    sqrt(blurredSqureImage - (blurredImage.mul(blurredImage)), varianceImage);
```

i try to improve performance using integral image. 
When i write loop of my own it was slower then original.

Are there any build-in opencv functions to speed up the process?
Or how can i write loops that can catch opencv performance?

Comment: It's actually not very clear what you're doing, or what you're trying to do. Any reason why you don't use [meanStdDev](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32967631/5008845), squaring the standard deviation?

Comment: I edited question. I look into meanStdDev. As far as i understand it is not suits for my needs.